# why does it not 'add to cart' when I click add to cart?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

When I try clicking on the add to cart button, it won't add to my cart. I don't know how to fix this. Is the code missing something important? I want it so that when I click on "add to cart" a product will be added so that it will appear in the shopping cart as an item added.

This is a class project I'm working on with a

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Printing Prime</title>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favi.png">
      <script src="js//bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css'>
      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css'>
      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:100'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/splitslick/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/featprod/style.css"
    </head>

    <body>

        <section id="" class="container-fluid cart">
            <article id="" class="col">
                <span class="open-modal">
                    <i id="carts" class="fa fa-shopping-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cart"></i>
                </span>
            </article>
        </section>

    <section id="" class="container-fluid">
        <article id="" class="row">
             <div id="mask"></div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="cart" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cart</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="show-cart table">

                    </table>
                    <div>Total price: $<span class="total-cart"></span></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Order now</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>

    <section id="products" class="container-fluid">
      <article id="" class="row">
        <div id="" class="col col-md-12 product-grid">
          <div class="col col-md-4 grid-item">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <img style="height: 30vh; width: 15vw;" src="img/hat1.png" alt="Avatar">
                  <h5 style="color:white;">Sad Face Cap</h5>
                    <h5 style="color:white;">$12.99</h5>
                  <div>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="# of items">
                    <a href="#" data-name="Sad Face Cap" data-price="12.99" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col col-md-4 grid-item">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <img style="height: 30vh; width: 15vw;" src="img/shirt1.png" alt="Avatar">
                  <h5 style="color:white;">Signature Tee</h5>
                  <div>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="# of items">
                    <a href="#" data-name="Signature Tee" data-price="14.99" id="submit" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=" col col-md-4 grid-item">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <img style="height: 30vh; width: 14vw;" src="img/hoodie1.png" alt="Avatar" >
                  <h5 style="color:white;">VHS Hoodie</h5>
                  <div>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="# of items" >
                    <a href="#" data-name="VHS Hoodie" data-price="16.99" id="submit" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>


      </body>
      </html>
```

```
    (js)

    function openModalBox(){
      var modal = $('.modal, #mask');
    $('.open-modal').on('click', function() {
     modal.fadeIn(300);
    });
    $('.close-modal, #mask').on('click', function() {
     modal.fadeOut(800);
    });
    }
    openModalBox();

    var shoppingCart = (function() {

      cart = [];


      function Item(name, price, count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.count = count;
      }


      function saveCart() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
      }



      function loadCart() {
        cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
      }
      if (sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") != null) {
        loadCart();
      }



      var obj = {};


      obj.addItemToCart = function(name, price, count) {
        for(var item in cart) {
          if(cart[item].name === name) {
            cart[item].count ++;
            saveCart();
            return;
          }
        }
        var item = new Item(name, price, count);
        cart.push(item);
        saveCart();
      }

      obj.setCountForItem = function(name, count) {
        for(var i in cart) {
          if (cart[i].name === name) {
            cart[i].count = count;
            break;
          }
        }
      };

      obj.removeItemFromCart = function(name) {
          for(var item in cart) {
            if(cart[item].name === name) {
              cart[item].count --;
              if(cart[item].count === 0) {
                cart.splice(item, 1);
              }
              break;
            }
        }
        saveCart();
      }


      obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function(name) {
        for(var item in cart) {
          if(cart[item].name === name) {
            cart.splice(item, 1);
            break;
          }
        }
        saveCart();
      }



      obj.totalCount = function() {
        var totalCount = 0;
        for(var item in cart) {
          totalCount += cart[item].count;
        }
        return totalCount;
      }


      obj.totalCart = function() {
        var totalCart = 0;
        for(var item in cart) {
          totalCart += cart[item].price * cart[item].count;
        }
        return Number(totalCart.toFixed());
      }


      obj.listCart = function() {
        var cartCopy = [];
        for(i in cart) {
          item = cart[i];
          itemCopy = {};
          for(p in item) {
            itemCopy[p] = item[p];

          }
          itemCopy.total = Number(item.price * item.count).toFixed(2);
          cartCopy.push(itemCopy)
        }
        return cartCopy;
      }


      return obj;
    })();


    $('.add-to-cart').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var name = $(this).data('name');
      var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
      shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
      displayCart();
    });


    $('.clear-cart').click(function() {
      shoppingCart.clearCart();
      displayCart();
    });


    function displayCart() {
      var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
      var output = "";
      for(var i in cartArray) {
        output += "<tr>"
          + "<td>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>" 
          + "<td>(" + cartArray[i].price + ")</td>"
          + "<td><div class='input-group'><button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn btn-primary' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">-</button>"
          + "<input type='number' class='item-count form-control' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>"
          + "<button class='plus-item btn btn-primary input-group-addon' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">+</button></div></td>"
          + "<td><button class='delete-item btn btn-danger' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">X</button></td>"
          + " = " 
          + "<td>" + cartArray[i].total + "</td>" 
          +  "</tr>";
      }
      $('.show-cart').html(output);
      $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
      $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
    }



    $('.show-cart').on("click", ".delete-item", function(event) {
      var name = $(this).data('name')
      shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
      displayCart();
    })



    $('.show-cart').on("click", ".minus-item", function(event) {
      var name = $(this).data('name')
      shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
      displayCart();
    })


    $('.show-cart').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
      var name = $(this).data('name')
      shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
      displayCart();
    })


    $('.show-cart').on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {
       var name = $(this).data('name');
       var count = Number($(this).val());
      shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
      displayCart();
    });

    displayCart();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO NhungN. Perhaps you should remove most of that code from your post because it is almost all irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that having all your logic client side like this will not make for a particularly secure ecommerce site.

Comment: Please update your question as to what the problem is. From first glance, you need to fix a few of your id attributes and you closing tags for some of your elements aren't aligned with their starting tags. It adds items to the "cart" but there are other problems as well when the user clicks the "+" and "-" buttons and the other buttons aren't functional as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 issues from the code snippet you have given.

Issue 1 - You are loading script.js (I assume that is where you have your page level scripting code) before loading jquery.

Solution - Move the jquery reference to the above and move script.js reference below.

1. jQuery
2. Bootstrap
3. Your custom js file (script.js)

Issue 2 -  Wrap your script code inside document.ready function.
Solution -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Your script code
})
```

Comment: Working version of your code snippet - https://codepen.io/SyedSami-UI/pen/qBBaXyv

Comment: the "+" and "-" buttons still aren't functional. But I guess that's how you want them to work.